# android sqlite, should i have two db's for two unrelated tables?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app that has database with 4 related tables, now I want to add a new table that is unrelated to those tables, is it better to create a new DB or just add the table to the old db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same db for the unrelated  table as well.

1. It will allow you to not get worked up for managing two separate databases.
2. You can write code for this table in a separate java file to make sure it does not get mixed up with the other code.

use

```
@Override        
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)           {

  }
```

to add create table statement with the new database version check applied if your app is live.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Just add the new table to the old db and change database version number.
and use

```
@Override        
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    // here you can update your existing db table 
   }
```

Comment: And don't forget the migration "script" :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to link to some helpful resources in the comment above.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)